# Ghost blog not creating RSS feed

Tags: javascript, rss, ghost-blog

The [Ghost FAQs](http://support.ghost.org/faq/#faq-1443) suggest that my ghost blog's rss feed can be found at 'exampleblog.com/rss'. However [my blog](http://markbennett.io) throws a 404 when I try to navigate to the '/rss' url. Any suggestions for where I might be going wrong?

In case it's helpful, the blog is hosted on github pages. Here are my production settings in config.js:

```
// ### Production
// When running Ghost in the wild, use the production environment
// Configure your URL and mail settings here
production: {
    url: 'http://markbennett.io',

      mail: {
          transport: 'SMTP',
          options: {
              service: 'Mailgun',
              auth: {
                  user: '[removed]', // mailgun username
                  pass: '[removed]'  // mailgun password
              }
          }
      },
                    database: {
      client: 'sqlite3',
        connection: {
            filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost.db')
        },
        debug: false
    },
    server: {
        // Host to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        // Port to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`, for iisnode set this to `process.env.PORT`
        port: '2368'
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks likes a GitHub pages 404 not a Ghost one. Make sure the url is actually going to the ghost app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your RSS is at http://markbennett.io/rss/index.rss. Make sure you update your template files, and be sure to update the `href` for the rss `<link>` tag in the `<head>`.